# Dudas sobre rutas de imagenes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, rutas

Dentro del emulador la ruta de una imagen me sale que es:

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/454980.png

Pero con el siguiente código:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        path = data.getData();
        imagen.setImageURI(path);
    }
}
```

Se obtiene esta ruta de la misma imagen:

> content://media/external/images/media/78

Al tratar de cargar la imagen con la ruta anterior la imagen no se ve y muestra este error:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /
>   content:/media/external/images/media/78: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory)

Quiero saber porque el método me da una ruta la cual no me lleva a la imagen que seleccione.

Con este código trato de cargar la imagen, destaco que la ruta obtenida con el método anterior la guardo en base de datos sqlite.

```
 private void buscar() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT foto FROM " + Utilidades.Tabla_Contacto + " WHERE " + Utilidades.Campo_telef + " = '"+numero + "'",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Toast.makeText(this,cursor.getString(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{
        imagen.setImageURI(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0)));

    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,e+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    db.close();
}
```

Comment: ¿y como estas tratando de cargar la imagen, puedes agregar el código?

Comment: Listo ahí agregué el código donde obtengo desde la base de datos la ruta que tenia guardada

Comment: ok lo que entiendo es que guardas esta ruta "content:/media/external/images/media/78" y después la obtienes de la base de datos para volver a obtener la imagen ?

Comment: exacto pero no me carga la imagen, pero si pongo esta ruta: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/454980.png si que me la carga sin problemas

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema con la solucion planteada?

Comment: Resolvio muy bien el tema de la ruta, pero aun así no me deja cargar la imagen con imagen.setImageUri(Uri.parse(imagePath)); si pongo la ruta directamente imagen.setImageUri(Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/454980.png")); funciona perfectamente, pero si pongo como anteriormente lo hice con una variable no funciona, sigue mandando este mensaje E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: / content:/media/external/images/media/78: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Corregí el error que seguía saliendo, al parecer la ruta contenía espacios en blanco y daba el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo asegurate de que tienes el permiso necesario para leer la ruta del directorio externo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Para obtener el Path correcto debes utilizar el [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html?hl=es-419):

```
private String getPathFromUri(Uri uri){

    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    return imagePath;

}
```

Tu código debe quedar mas o menos asi:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       path = data.getData(); // Path debe ser tipo Uri
       String imagePath = getPathFromUri(path); // Aqui te devuelve el path correcto como un String
       imagen.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath)); // Conviertes el string a Uri para cargar la imagen
    }
}
```

Mas información: [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html?hl=es-419)

Nota: si te da warnings de posible casos de null, validalos para evitarlos, saludos.